# how to pass parameters to runnable method

Tags: java, android, runnable

I have a function `functionAcceptsMethod` which accepts a runnable method as a parameter, I want to call `functionAcceptsMethod` by passing a method with parameters.

when I call `functionAcceptsMethod` by passing without parameters its fine but how to pass a function with parameters.

here is an example

```
 private void testFun() {
        functionAcceptsMethod(this::funWithoutParams);
        functionAcceptsMethod(this::funWithParams); // this where I need to pass params
        //functionAcceptsMethod(() -> funWithParams("abcd")); // I tried this, is this the right 
         //way?
    }

private void funWithoutParams() {
    //do something
}

private void funWithParams(String testString) {
    //do something
}

private  void functionAcceptsMethod(Runnable method) {
    method.run();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way is to have a version of your `functionAcceptsMethod` method with the parameter:

```java
private void <T> functionAcceptsMethod(Consumer<T> method, T argument) {
    method.accept(argument);
}
```

Note that `Runnable#run` is a functional interface without a parameter, so you cannot use it here. You have to use [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). Now you can do this:

```java
functionAcceptsMethod(this::funWithParams, "abc");
```

Check out [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) for more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
The approach

`functionAcceptsMethod(() -> funWithParams("abcd"));`

is ok, if your purpose is to just pass method reference and get args in parameters of `functionAcceptsMethod` method then use `Consumer<T>` as function receiver argument

As you wanted an example:

```java
public static <T> void functionAcceptsMethod(Consumer<T> consumer, T t){
    consumer.accept(t);
}
```

This is a generic version and will accept any method that has single input parameter. and an example of usage:

```java
public void example(){
    // Automatic type inferring
    functionAcceptsMethod(this::func, "f");
    functionAcceptsMethod(this::func2, 0);
    // Explicit type specification
    functionAcceptsMethod<Float>(this::func3, 0f);
}
public void func(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
public void func2(int i){
    System.out.println(i);
}
public void func3(float f){
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your response, method.run which I have in `functionAcceptsMethod ` will not work to execute the function with parameters?

Comment: also can you suggest how to modify `functionAcceptsMethod ` with Consumer please, I have never used Consumer before

Comment: for your first question, not at all you can't use that method you wrote for executing any function. I updated the answer and added some generic examples that u can use for any function with single parameters. if u want a general method for all type of functions you have 2 possible approaches: 1. getting method reference and parameters as array and using reflection two execute [not good approach, reflection is not efficient comparing to direct execution] 2. design an interface and have ur functions to follow the input/output signature of that. @BRDroid